# i am facing issues in using spring crud reprositry

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMqController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'recordsReprositry'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.rabbitmq.config.RecordsReprositry' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: please, show the way you defined the repository. the stacktrace is not enough to help you out

Comment: package com.rabbitmq.config;                                                                                  

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface RecordsReprositry extends CrudRepository<Records, Long>{

 public Records findById(UUID id);
 
}

Comment: you can edit your question to provide additional info. Paste the controller and the repository code there

Comment: these are annotations with autowired and requestmapping

@RestController
public class RabbitMqController {
 Autowired
 private RecordsReprositry recordsReprositry;

 RequestMapping(name="/btsocr", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String btsOCR() throws Exception
 {
  


  return "Working";
 }

}

Comment: Why are you defining beans within someone else's package namespace?

Comment: I am wondering why a repository bean was created because there is the mismatch between id types - Long and UUID

Comment: Sometimes, everything is right while setting up a new project and you need to delete cached jars and download/update them all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are annotated interface..while you should put @repository to its implementation class.

```
package com.rabbitmq.config;                                                                                  

import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public **interface** RecordsReprositry extends CrudRepository<Records, Long>{

    public Records findById(UUID id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JPA from spring... (DOC : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Example:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityName,Long> {
    // here you can write your query; example:
    EntityName findByAttribute(Type value);
    // or
    @Query("SELECT * FROM EntityName t WHERE t.ID=?1")
    EntityName findByID(Long id);
}
```

Then you can use this repository in service (you must use autowired)

Example:

```
@Service
public class MyService{
    @Autowired 
    private MyRepository repo;

    // here you can call in a method your query
    public EntityName example() {
        EntityName e = repo.findByID((long)1);
        return e;
    }
}
```

Important: the repository your must use it only in service and the service you must use it in controller